# How to write a fake local server with Terminal

Tags: networking, terminal, localhost, backend

I'm making network requests with my mobile app. I would like to simulate a server for error handling because the server I will eventually make requests to is not up yet

I don't want to spend a lot of time coding my own server

I want to make a request to a server, and have the server respond with..

- a 400 response
- a 200 response
- no response

Answer (score 0):

Terminal commands for each test

everywhere that says 11.11.11.11 you should enter your IP Address instead

400 response test

```
while true; do echo -e "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\n\n $(date)" | nc -l 11.11.11.11 1500; sleep 3; done
```

when the test is complete, hit control + c in the terminal until the process stops

200 response test

```
 while true; do echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n $(date)" | nc -l 11.11.11.11 1500;  sleep 3; done
```

when the test is complete, hit control + c in the terminal until the process stops

No response test

```
nc -l 11.11.11.11 1500
```

when the test is complete, hit control + c in the terminal until the process stops